# Не открывается картинка на сайте

Tags: css

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #333;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro {
    width: :100%;
    height: 100vh;

    background-image: : url("../image/intro.jpg") no-repeat center;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Mogo</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="intro">
 <div class="container">
    <h1>Mogo</h1>
    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вёрстку покажите, но вангую, что у родительского по отношению к intro блоку не указана высота.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: : url("../image/intro.jpg") no-repeat center;
```

Два двоеточия между image и url. Так и должно быть?

И в классе intro:

```
width: :100%;
```